# Accessing a database in a separate thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, android-activity, android-asynctask

How do you access a `SQLiteDatabase` database in a separate thread (ie: an `AsyncTask`) of an `Activity` and make sure that you always leave it in a legal state?

If I understand correctly, the thread can be killed at any moment and the database might remain open, potentially giving an `IllegalStateException` (*SQLiteDatabase 
created and never closed*) at a latter time.

How do you deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `AsyncTask` is managed by your `Activity`, then `Activity` may cancel `AsyncTask` in proper time (when it becomes vulnerable to be killed by OS, e.g. after `Activity.onPause()`) so `AsyncTask.onCancelled()` will be called where you may close the DB.

If your `AsyncTask` (or a `Thread`) is not managed by your `Activity` then your are in trouble and should consider redesigning your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. You can register a `Runtime.addShutdownHook(..)` and close database there.
2. Create custom `Application` and implement `onLowMemory()` where you close the database.

Comment: Is there any guarantee that addShutdownHook will always run after all activities have been destroyed?